# No matching function for call / Candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided

Tags: c++

First off, I am a beginner at C++ coding, so if possible try to explain things in the simplest possible terms so that I can make heads or tails of it.

I have done a lot of research, but most of the examples just don't make any sense to me. I have tried implementing various solutions, but I either get the same bug or make things worse.

The program is supposed to be able to take in a string of Roman numerals, and convert them to an integer value. Since this is a homework assignment, I must all of this within a `Roman_int` class and perform the operation through member functions within the class.

The program I have created  contains a member function called `as_int()` which does the work of converts a string of roman numeral into a numeric integer value. As far as I can tell, that part works fine.

Another thing to note, I am using a special header provided by my university, which handles things like using the std library, so things might look a bit weird.

Here's what I have:

```
#include "std_lib_facilities_4.h"
/* 
M=1000
D=500
C=100
L=50
X=10
V=5
I=1
*/

class Roman_int
{
    string r;

 public:
    int as_int()
    {
        int val;
        for(int i=r.size()-1; i>0; --i)
        {
            if(i==r.size()-1)
            {
                switch(r[i])
                {
                    case 'M':
                        val+=1000;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        val+=500;
                        break;
                    case 'C':
                        val+=100;
                        break;
                    case 'L':
                        val+=50;
                        break;
                    case 'X':
                        val+=10;
                        break;
                    case 'V':
                        val+=5;
                        break;
                    case 'I':
                        val+=1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        error("invalid input");
                        break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                switch(r[i])
                {
                    case 'M':
                        val+=1000;
                        break;
                    case 'D':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'M')
                            val-=500;
                        else
                            val+=500;
                            break;
                    case 'C':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'M' || r[i+1]== 'D')
                            val-=100;
                        else
                            val+=100;
                            break;
                    case 'L':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'M' || r[i+1]== 'D' || r[i+1]== 'C')
                            val-=50;
                        else
                            val+=50;
                            break;
                    case 'X':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'M' || r[i+1]== 'D' || r[i+1]== 'C' || r[i+1]== 'L')
                            val-=10;
                        else
                            val+=10;
                            break;
                    case 'V':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'M' || r[i+1]== 'D' || r[i+1]== 'C' || r[i+1]== 'L'  || r[i+1]== 'X')
                            val-=5;
                        else
                            val+=5;
                            break;
                    case 'I':
                        if(r[i+1]== 'I')
                            val+=1;
                        else
                            val-=1;
                        break;
                    default:
                        error("invalid input");
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        return val;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& is, Roman_int& roman)
    {
        string rom_num;
        is >> rom_num;
        if(!is) return is;
        roman = Roman_int(rom_num);
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Roman_int& roman)
    {
        cout << roman.r << endl;
        return os;
    }

};



int main()
{
    Roman_int r;
    cout << "Enter a Roman numeral in all capital letters: " << endl;
    cin >> r;
    cout << "Roman " << r << " equals " << r.as_int() << endl;
}
```

The problem I am having is with declaring my Roman_int object in my main function. I am getting a similar error to before:

```
hw6_pr3.cpp: In function ‘std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, Roman_int&)’:
hw6_pr3.cpp:114:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘Roman_int::Roman_int(String&)’
   roman = Roman_int(rom_num);
                            ^
hw6_pr3.cpp:114:28: note: candidates are:
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note: Roman_int::Roman_int()
 class Roman_int
       ^
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note: Roman_int::Roman_int(const Roman_int&)
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘String’ to ‘const Roman_int&’
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note: Roman_int::Roman_int(Roman_int&&)
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘String’ to ‘Roman_int&&’
```

From what I have read, I'm pretty sure it has something to do with either the default constructor or how my class is being initialized, but I have no idea where I am supposed to go from there, as I have never encountered this sort of problem with any of the classes I have created. If anyone could explain this in simple terms, that would extremely helpful.

---

EDIT: I added a constructor to the `Roman_int` class:

```
Roman_int(const string& r) : r(r) {}
```

however I am still getting an error with calling `Roman_int r;` in my main function. This is the new error message:

```
    hw6_pr3.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
hw6_pr3.cpp:131:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘Roman_int::Roman_int()’
  Roman_int r;
            ^
hw6_pr3.cpp:131:12: note: candidates are:
hw6_pr3.cpp:124:2: note: Roman_int::Roman_int(const String&)
  Roman_int(const string& r) : r(r) { }
  ^
hw6_pr3.cpp:124:2: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note: Roman_int::Roman_int(const Roman_int&)
 class Roman_int
       ^
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note: Roman_int::Roman_int(Roman_int&&)
hw6_pr3.cpp:17:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

Comment: Do you have `Roman_int(String&)` constructor defined ?

Comment: Even without a constructor, you could just change `operator>>` to `return is >> roman.r;`, if you don't want to do any validation....

Comment: @P0W I don't think so, what exactly do you mean by that? I'm sorry, it's been a long day trying to figure out how to get this to work.

Comment: @TonyD Part of the homework requires I use operator overloading. Also, I'm not really sure what that means, I'm still a freshman and C++ is pretty new to me.

Comment: @ P0W I edited the post, and added my new error, unfortunately it's awfully similar to the old one. If it helps, I am pretty sure that I am compiling on C++ 14, on a remote Linux server.

Comment: Do you *really* think this line is unambiguous and clear? `Roman_int(const string& r) : r(r) {}`.  You refer to two different variables, both called `r`.  Which one do you mean?

Comment: So you went from only a default constructor (so with parameter did not work) to only a constructor with a parameter (so your one *without* parameter does not work). Perhaps you need *both* (or a default parameter)?

Comment: Ohhhh! OK thanks a ton guys, I'm an idiot. I need to make a constructor for both cases, with and without a string parameter since I called both in my function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string rom_num;
roman = Roman_int(rom_num);
```

This expects a `Roman_int::Roman_int(const std::string& argument)` implemented somewhere. You are calling a constructor which doesn't exist for the class.

Implement it inside the definition:

```
Roman_int(const std::string& r) : r(r) { }
```

Comment: I implemented your solution, but I am still having issues. I think it might have something to do with what P0W said, and defining the Roman_int(String&) constructor, but I'm not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: @Araganor: Jack's `Roman_int(const std::string& r) : r(r) { }` is what P0W meant by "`Roman_int(String&)` constructor" (he just miscapitalised string, omitted the const and std:: thinking them obvious, and didn't provide the implementation like Jack has).  If you're "still having issues", nobody will be able to help unless you share them....

Comment: @Tony D: Edited my post to reflect the new error I am encountering, if you need any more information please let me know. I really appreciate this help, I am also doing what I can to try and figure this out on my own.

Comment: I added this constructor, but forgot to include one for the default case, I've got it working now.